# c linked list delete smallest element

Tags: c, linked-list

Lists seem really hard for me. I want to find the smallest element in a file: `1 5 8 6 4 8 6 48 9`. It's 1 and I want to delete that `1`. I can find the smallest element but can not delete it. I find the smallest element place but not the value. I tried copying deleting function from the web, however I cant understand it due to the fact that I'm really new to C. It writes an error that dereferencing to incomplete type. Please help. Post whole code because it should be more convenient to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedList {
    int value;
    struct linkedList *next;
} linkedList, head;

linkedList *readList(linkedList *head) {
    FILE *dataFile;
    dataFile = fopen("duom.txt", "r");
    if (dataFile == NULL) {
        printf("Nepasisekė atidaryti failo\n");
    } else {
        printf("Duomenų failą pavyko atidaryti\n");
    }
    while (!feof (dataFile))
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
            fscanf(dataFile, "%d", &head->value);
            head->next = NULL;
        } else {
            struct linkedList *current = head;
            struct linkedList *temp = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            fscanf(dataFile, "%d", &temp->value);
            current->next = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    return head;
}

void search(linkedList *head, int *lowest) {
    int a[100];
    int i = 0;
    int minimum;
    int b = 0;
    linkedList *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        a[i] = current->value;
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }
    b = i;
    i = 0;
    minimum = a[0];
    while (b > 0) {
        if (minimum > a[i]) {
            minimum = a[i];
            lowest = i;
        }
        i++;
        b--;
    }
}

void deleteNode(struct node **head_ref, int key) {
    struct node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;

    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) {
        *head_ref = temp->next;   // Changed head
        free(temp);               // free old head
        return;
    }

    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL) 
        return;
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}

void printList(linkedList *head) {
    linkedList *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    return;
}

int main() {
    linkedList *A = NULL;
    A = readList(A);
    search(A);
    head = head->next;
    minimum = head->value;
    headk->next = head->next;
    free(head);
    printList(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Post whole code". Sorry, that's not how Stackoverflow works. We are not here to complete your code for you. "It writes an error that dereferencing to incomplete type". What is "it"? The compiler? The program? The IDE? Please provide the *exact* error that is occurring.

Comment: `search(A);` different signature.

Comment: Thanks for criticism, Will improve and do better

Comment: @AdomasArabella I think that the question was perfectly good....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if this program can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void push(struct node **head_ref, int new_data) {
    struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void deleteNode(struct node **head_ref, int key) {
    struct node *temp = *head_ref, *prev;
    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) {
        *head_ref = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp == NULL) return;
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}

void printList(struct node *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void min(struct node **q) {
    struct node *r;
    int min = INT_MAX;;
    r = *q;
    while (r != NULL) {
        if (r->data < min) {
            min = r->data;
        }
        r = r->next;
    }
    printf("The min is %d", min);
    deleteNode(q, min);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen("duom.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &i);
    while (!feof(file)) {
        push(&head, i);
        fscanf(file, "%d", &i);
    }
    fclose(file);
    puts("Created Linked List: ");
    printList(head);
    min(&head);
    puts("\nLinked List after Deletion of minimum: ");
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

file `duom.txt`

```
1 5 8 6 4 8 6 48 9
```

Test

```
./a.out 
Created Linked List: 
 9  48  6  8  4  6  8  5  1 The min is 1

Linked List after Deletion of minimum: 
 9  48  6  8  4  6  8  5 ⏎
```

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct linkedList{
    int value;
    struct linkedList *next;
} linkedList, node;

linkedList *readList(void){
    FILE *dataFile;
    dataFile = fopen("duom.txt", "r");
    if(dataFile == NULL) {
        perror("file open");
        return NULL;
    }

    int v;
    node head = {0, NULL}, *curr = &head;
    while (1 == fscanf(dataFile, "%d", &v)){
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(new_node == NULL){
            perror("malloc");
            break;
        }
        new_node->value = v;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        curr = curr->next = new_node;
    }
    fclose(dataFile);
    return head.next;
}

int searchMin(linkedList *head){
    if(head == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: The list MUST NOT be NULL.\n", __func__);
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    int min = head->value;
    node *p = head->next;
    while(p){
        if(p->value < min)
            min = p->value;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return min;
}

void deleteNode(node **head_ref, int key){
    node *curr = *head_ref, *prev = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL && curr->value != key){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == NULL) return;//not found
    if(prev)
        prev->next = curr->next;
    else
        *head_ref = curr->next;
    free(curr);
}

void printList(linkedList *head){
    node *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", current->value);
        current = current -> next;
    }
    puts("NULL");
}

void freeList(linkedList *list){
    while(list){
        node *temp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main(void){
    linkedList *A = readList();
    int min = searchMin(A);
    printList(A);
    deleteNode(&A, min);
    printList(A);
    freeList(A);

    return 0;
}
```